# Run Simple C# Console in OSX using VSCode

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code

I created simple 'HelloWorld' console app of .NET core in OSX.

The project.json file contains "run" command, and when I execute "dnx run" from bash it executes the program.

However when I execute ">dnx: Run Command" from the C# extension in VSCode command palette, I get: "there are no entries to pick from"

The odd thing is that when I execute ">dnx: Restore Packages" from the command palette the terminal is opened and proper "dnu restore" command runs properly.

The project structure is the output of yeoman aspnet generator.

What am I doing wrong?